# How make sympy.printing.latex use Newton's notation for time derivatives

Tags: latex, sympy

While in qtconsole, I can import `init_vprinting` from `sympy.physics.mechanics` and then use `dynamicsymbols` to acquire dotted derivatives. 
But when I use `latex` printer, I get 'da/dt' instead.

```
a = dynamicsymbols('a')
a.diff(t)
```

[image]

```
In: latex(a.diff(t))
Out: '\\frac{d}{d t} a{\\left (t \\right )}'
```

And I want something like

```
'\\dot{a}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy's standard LaTeX printer does not contain any special logic for handling the objects of Physics modules. The special rules for printing Physics objects are implemented by the Physics module, as a function [`vlatex`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/vector/api/printing.html#vlatex):

```
from sympy.physics.vector import vlatex
vlatex(a.diff(t))   #  outputs '\\dot{a}'
```